# Radio button focus goes out when we pressed down arrow key

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, accessibility, loading

I have been encountering an accessibility issue for the past few days related to a component in Angular called main-component. Within this main component, there are four different templates. However, depending on the selection of a radio button, other templates are displayed on the screen. The problem arises when these templates are not initially loaded on the screen. Upon loading, the focus is lost, preventing users from using the up or down arrow keys. This accessibility issue occurs when tabbing through the radio buttons.

Thank you.

main-component.ts

```
<div>

<form>
       <custom-radio-button [value]="'A'" (change)="radioChange('A')">A</custom-radio-button>
       <custom-radio-button [value]="'B'" (change)="radioChange('B')">B</custom-radio-button>
       <custom-radio-button [value]="'C'" (change)="radioChange('C')">C</custom-radio-button>
       <custom-radio-button [value]="'D'" (change)="radioChange('D')">D</custom-radio-button>
</form>

<ng-template *ngIf="selection == 'A'">A</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="selection == 'B'">B</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="selection == 'C'">C</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="selection == 'D'">D</ng-template>

</div>
```

main-component.ts (here we have change event)

```
   radioChange(value) {
     this.selection = value;
   }
```

Is there anyone who can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<custom-radio-button [value]="'A'" (change)="radioChange('A', $event)">A</custom-radio-button>
```

```js
radioChange(value, event) {
  this.selection = value;
  setTimeout(() => { event.target.focus(); });
}
```

This should set the focus back on your component. Not a solution, but an immediate workaround. If you want a real solution, please provide an example of the issue on stackblitz !